# Best approach to saving out some data to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have weather data for multiple "stations" (most of these stations are located at airports). The data is currently just an assortment of arrays and the data was retrieved from web APIs.

For example:

Station: Chicago (O'Hare Airport)
Temperature: 80
WindSpeed: 10
Description: Clear

Station: Portland International Airport
Temperature: 71
WindSpeed: 10
Description: Cloudy

I want to write the data out to a JSON file. What's the best approach to take with this?

---

So a little later I tried to solve this. I created an Object
var stationsObjects = new Object();

Iterated through all of the weather stations and did this:

```
stationsObjects[station] = new Object();
stationsObjects[station].Temperature = value.Temperature;
stationsObjects[station].Windspeed = value.Windspeed;
stationsObjects[station].Pressure = value.Pressure;
stationsObjects[station].theTimeStamp = value.theTimeStamp;
stationsObjects[station].textDescription = value.textDescription;
```

So now I have an object full of all of the stations, essentially already in JSON format, correct?

```
{
    "KBWI": {
        "Temperature": 73,
        "Windspeed": 3,
        "Pressure": 101560,
        "theTimeStamp": "2018-05-11T12:54:00+00:00",
        "textDescription": "Mostly Clear"
    },
    "KDCA": {
        "Temperature": 74,
        "Windspeed": 3,
        "Pressure": 101660,
        "theTimeStamp": "2018-05-11T12:52:00+00:00",
        "textDescription": "Partly Cloudy"
    },
...
```

I just need to save to disk, right? Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an array that contains each of those lines as strings (and that those strings always the same format), you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

I came up with the following regex from the examples you have provided

```
/(?:Station: )([\w'\s()]+)(?: Temperature: )(\d+)(?: WindSpeed: )(\d+)(?: Description: )(\w+)/i
```

You use it in the following way

```
let data = [
    'Station: Chicago(O\'Hare Airport) Temperature: 80 WindSpeed: 10 Description: Clear',
    'Station: Portland International Airport Temperature: 71 WindSpeed: 10 Description: Cloudy'
];

const regex = /^(?:Station: )([\w'\s()]+)(?: Temperature: )(\d+)(?: WindSpeed: )(\d+)(?: Description: )(\w+)$/i;

const results = [];

data.forEach(dataPoint => {
    const match = dataPoint.match(regex);
    results.push({
        station: match[1],
        temperature: match[2],
        windSpeed: match[3],
        description: match[4],
    });
});

console.log(results); // A javascript array cotaining the data as objects
```

Now to write it to a file you use the build-in [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module

```
fs.writeFileSync('./wheatherData.json', JSON.stringify(results));
```

Now. This **ONLY** works if *all* your data follows the same format as the two examples in your question. If that is not the case, [read up on regular expressions](https://regexone.com), and build one that fits your data.